# Good approach for dynamically equiped items in 3D game libGDX

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

I struggle to achieve effect described in the title. What I've done so far is that I've created two separated models in blender, one for character and one for sword, both with armature. I tried to attach node, from sword Model to hand node from Character model and than creating an instance, but I didnt see any effect. Than I created two model instances, one for sword and one for character. Next I tried to copy tranformation matrix for sword instance like this:

```
    sword.transform.set(weaponNode.globalTransform);
```

where weaponNode is a node from character instance, more specific a hand. It gave some effect,because now the sword makes same movement, as animated character, but I cant change it's position. Also when I try to print  Matrix4 for weaponNode it does'nt change. Any corrections to my approach? Maybe I'm missunderstanding the concept?

EDIT1:
I realized that I should move not the instance of the character but the main node (armature) of it. It will not only translate the whole mesh, but also all the nodes. That allowed me to put a sword into the hand of this character and move it along with him. It also works when performing animation, so the sword goes along with the hand.

EDIT2:
It appears that I don't need any armature in sword model. All I need to do is to set a proper bone in the hand of character and in render method just to copy the Matrix4 of this bone and set it to the sword instance as above.